# Insert HTML code to div onClick but does not replace existing code

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to insert HTML code to make a "list". I've seen examples of innerHTML but that just replaces the existing code. How can I add more code without replacing the current code?

```js
var addTo = document.querySelector(".activePage")[0];
var addHTML = '
<div id="item1">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>'

addTo.innerHTML(addHTML)'
```

```html
<nav class="activePage"><nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insertAdjacentHtml. Docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML.

```
var addTo = document.querySelector(".activePage");

var addHTML = '<div id="item1"><h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>

addTo.insertAdjacentHtml(addHTML, 'beforeEnd')
```

'beforeEnd' means it will add right before the end of the element(inside the element).

Comment: I'm getting an error, apparently addTo becomes undefined

Comment: Edit: It worked after removing the [0] from the end of querySelector, any idea why?

Comment: It is because querySelector returns only 1 element, since it worked for you could you upvote and make it the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to append to the HTML inside the `nav` tag instead of replace it with a new value.

```js
var addTo = document.querySelector(".activePage");
var addHTML = '<div id="item1"><h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>';
addTo.innerHTML += addHTML;
```

```html
<nav class="activePage">
<nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your HTML to the existing HTML inside of the target element using `+=`.

```js
function addNew() {
  var addTo = document.querySelectorAll(".activePage")[0];
  var addHTML = '<div id="item1"><h1>This is a heading</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>'
  addTo.innerHTML += addHTML
}
```

```html
<nav class="activePage">
  <button onclick="addNew()">add</button>
  <nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're after is the append feature.
https://api.jquery.com/append/
or
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Below is a jquery example. I have used this example as i think it's easier to understand what's going on at first glance

example:

```
    $(".your_div").append(html_load());
    
    function html_load() {
       return  '<li class="list"> list item </li>'
    }
```

This will result in the below:

```
    <div class="your_div">
        <li>start</li>
    </div>
```

being updated to:

```
    <div class="your_div">
        <li>start</li>
        <li class="list"> list item </li>
    </div>
```